# I changed my password to none and now i cant authenticate nor even cant do sudo?

Tags: password, sudo, privileges

I have admin rights. Could there be a way to change back my pass. I dont even know whats my password is because I already set it to "none' now its very hard to install apps. Need help please ! Fast.

Comment: Changing the password will fix your problem.
Just google "how to change ubuntu password." Definitely a duplicate.

Comment: Ouh okay thanks dude. This creeping me out im a new linux user and suddenly get this error damn -.-

Comment: You should always have an administrative account with a password.  If you want another account without a password you can create one but it won't let you administer your system.  But you can reset the password as described in the duplicate question.